# How do I execute more than one statement with php_exec?

Tags: php, child-process

I have a carousel with same images, when the users clicks over one I show a form with e-mail and password. When the submit action is send via AJAX I pass image id, e-mail and password to PHP callback.
After validate the credentials in my PHP I call a node.js script, but I just can execute one node.js script per time.

Is there a way to execute many node.js each one with same id image name and diferents e-mail and password with php_exec?

```
My Carousel code:
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div id="owl_carousel" class="owl-carousel owl-theme" style="opacity: 1; display: block;">

    <div class="owl-wrapper-outer"><div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 7296px; left: 0px; display: block;"><div class="owl-item" style="width: 228px;"><div class="item">
                                <img role="button" tabindex="-1" data-trigger="hover" data-content="lollipop" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" alt="lollipop" id="lollipop" style="width: 170px; height: 170px;" src="img/clients/lollipop.png" data-original-title="" title="">
</div></div>
</div>
```

And here my php code:

```
My PHP Code

<?php 

class validateForm {

    function formValidate() {


        // Informations passes from form
        $username = trim($_POST['username']);
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);
        $filename = trim($_POST['file']);
        $retorno = array();

        // CasperJS call
        $nodejs_run = "node";
        $script = "/usr/share/node/parser.js";

        // Check if POST is null
        if ( (empty($username) &&  empty($password)) || ($username == null || $password == null) ) {
            $retorno['error'] = "Fill the form!"; 
            echo json_encode($retorno);
        } else {

            // Execute to CasperJS via asynchronous process
            try {
                exec("{$nodejs_run} {$script} {$username} {$password} {$filename} 2>&1", $output,$retval);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $retorno['failure'] = "The request failure!";
            }

            if (($retval) == '0'){
                $retorno['success'] = $output;
                echo json_encode($retorno);
            } else {
                $retorno['error'] = $output;
                echo json_encode($retorno);
            }

        } // end of if block

        return false;

    } // end function

} // end class

// Call function
$instValidadeForm = new validateForm; //create instance of class
echo $instValidadeForm->formValidate(); // access method of class

?>
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: I don't understand, you want to execute one after another or both at the same time?

Comment: It looks like you are passing unvalidated, unescaped and unauthenticated user input to a shell. This is a big security risk. What happens if the user enters a username like "; ls; echo"? Because it looks like you are dealing with uploaded files, it would be really easy for a user to execute the file they just uploaded using the password "; sh". Also, because the credentials are being passed as command line arguments, somebody could get lucky and see the credentials of other users by using "ps aux".

Comment: @oscargilfc, I wish to execute at the same time.
I wish to give the users choose more then one target to execute at same time.

Comment: @mdonoughe, I have same validations to scape same characters.

Comment: Okay. I don't see them here so maybe they're removed from to simplify the question. Make sure you are doing that on the server side and before you call exec.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using exec() you could separate multiple commands with &&

eg:

```
exec("$command1 && $command2 && $command3", $output, $retval);
```

In this case, $command2 only executes if $command1 succeeds, $command3 only executes if $command2 succeeds.  And $retval will hold the return status of the last command to execute.

Comment: I know that can i cocatenate commands with &&, but the cases here is: the id image is associate to diferents nodejs scripts example:

If the user click over lollipop and kitkat i have to execute two nodejs scripts lollipop.js and kitkat.js at the same time.

I hope to be clear.